# How to get item attachment size in JavaScript

Tags: list-view, list-form, attachments

I have a SharePoint list with attachments in its items. Now I want to show the attachment size in the item View Form and Edit form. But I cannot find a JavaScript API to get the attachment size.

I tried the OData service but it only returns the file name. Apparently I cannot download these files...
`_api/web/lists/getbytitle('My%20Documents')/items(1)/AttachmentFiles`

So in short, How can I get item attachment size in JavaScript? (I am using SharePoint 2013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the `serverrelativeurl` of the file from your request. Pass it to another request like so: `_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Lists/TestList/Attachments/1/blabla.xlsx')`. This will give you the file length in Bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Use below REST API example

```
url: "<app web url>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web
    /getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Shared Documents/filename.docx')/Length
```

For more info: 
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx)